# Why is $(div#id) slower than $(#id)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, google-chrome

Unless there is something wrong with my test, when I run this jsfiddle on Chrome I'm getting around 11ms for an `$("#id")` selector and 56ms for a `$(div#id)` selector.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    startTime = new Date().getTime();
    for (i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        s = $("#idC12");
    }           
    $("#idResults").html("c12 by id only time: "+elapsedMilliseconds(startTime));

    startTime = new Date().getTime();
    for (i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        s = $("div#idC12");
    }           
    $("#classResults").html("c12 by tagname#id: "+elapsedMilliseconds(startTime));
});

function elapsedMilliseconds(startTime)
{
    var n = new Date();
    var s = n.getTime();
    var diff = s - startTime;
    return diff;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MhWUc/

Comment: In addition to the very good answers below, I would say as you should have unique Id's on a page, there's no point being so specific as div#id...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's because `$("#id")` internally uses the native [document.getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementById) function, which uses a map linking from the id to the (unique) element having this id.

Here's the relevant code in jQuery source :

```
        // Easily-parseable/retrievable ID or TAG or CLASS selectors
        rquickExpr = /^(?:#([\w-]+)|(\w+)|\.([\w-]+))$/
        ...
        // Speed-up: Sizzle("#ID")
        if ( (m = match[1]) ) {
            if ( nodeType === 9 ) {
                elem = context.getElementById( m );
                // Check parentNode to catch when Blackberry 4.6 returns
                // nodes that are no longer in the document #6963
                if ( elem && elem.parentNode ) {
                    // Handle the case where IE, Opera, and Webkit return items
                    // by name instead of ID
                    if ( elem.id === m ) {
                        results.push( elem );
                        return results;
                    }
                } else {
                    return results;
                }
            } else {
                // Context is not a document
                if ( context.ownerDocument && (elem = context.ownerDocument.getElementById( m )) &&
                    contains( context, elem ) && elem.id === m ) {
                    results.push( elem );
                    return results;
                }
            }
```

You'll notice that :

- it's used when the regex detects the `#someId` form
- any provided context only adds a test, and doesn't make it faster

Note that this rule is still true outside of jQuery, when defining CSS rules or using `document.querySelector` : when you know the id, there is nothing faster than using `document.getElementById` (apart a cached element...).

Comment: Ready, set, GO! You win :)

Comment: To add to this, $(div#id) has to run an extra selector on div. I'd have to look at the sizzle engine to see if $(#id) is first looked up and checked to ensure div-ness, but I imagine ir runs a querySelectAll(div) first, then checks for the id.

Comment: Sometimes I forget why I use jQuery, and then I see some of the comments in there and remember why. It's a dark, dark world out there...

Comment: also, while the `id` attribute *should* be unique within an HTML document, if its not then `$("#id")` will *only* return the first element that matches that `id`, as `getElementById()` would. However `$("*#id")` will return all that satisfy the criteria.

Answer (score 2):

Been awhile since I've been in the source, but I know that `#some-id` selectors used to be handled by `document.getElementById()`, whereas more complex ones (e.g., `tagName#some-id`) have to go through sizzle and ultimately through `document.querySelectorAll`.

Answer (score 1):

`$('div#id')` is slower because it doesn't map directly to the native `getElementById()` method.

Answer (score 0):

When you use div#id, first all the divs are selected.

When you use #id, it goes directly to the table of ids.

Comment: Isn't it still a right-to-left implementation under the hood?

Comment: @jmar777 I don't think so. I think that's how CSS works, not jQuery's selection process. I swear I just read something about this. Maybe I'm wrong. I'll look for it

Comment: @jmar777 Or, it could be a special case where jQuery looks for the `#` anywhere in the string, and then maps the call directly to `getElementById` instead of just passing it to `querySelectorAll`

Comment: Right to left?   Wouldn't it need to get a container on the left before getting specific items in the container...on the right?  Maybe when using combination selectors ie withspace/comma operators.

Comment: @jmar777 Whether or not that's true, the OP proves that it doesn't read individual groups that way. It may read the whole selector from right to left, by groups, but the example provided only has one group - `div#id` (or `#id`). There's no reason to read individual groups from right to left. It would be different if it were `div #id`.

Comment: @jmar777 And as I suspected, the answer with the most votes (which shows the jQuery source) proves that it uses a special case when the selector string contains a "#" character.

Comment: @Ian I think that thread is more relavant for `#foo .bar` style selectors, then `.foo#bar`.  And the regex in the provided source doesn't match `tagName#id` selectors.  However, you may be right about the right-to-left only applying at a "group" level. Think I might have to dig in some more on that one...